# How to generate unique id only numbers with fixed length (max 10 characters) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I want to apply a unique ids non-obvious but with the hope of no more than 10 characters (fixed length) and only numbers.

Now using `SecureRandom.random_number (10 ** 9)`, but I doubt in the future if duplication problems arise, also once implemented `DateTime.now.strftime('% Q')` in hopes of finding a unique id per millisecond, but it produced 13 characters.

For now, I'm just posting the question. If you happen to know how to do this, I'd appreciate it

Comment: this is actually used for the order id, so that someone who orders has no trouble when mentioning the id. if it's an alphabet, it's complicated enough for someone to mention it, especially if it's more than 10 characters long.

Comment: OK. Can you choose to use sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.) rather than random ones?  Does each order ID have to be hard to guess?  Is the order ID the only thing someone needs to access information about an order?

Comment: I think the serial number is too easy to guess. yes the order id is the only thing that someone needs to know the details of the order, this is like an invoice number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want hard-to-guess 10-digit IDs, then `SecureRandom` is hard to beat.

But note that to generate a 10-*digit* ID, it is better to pass `10 ** 10` rather than `10 ** 9` to `SecureRandom.random_number`. Note that with this, the chance of producing a duplicate number becomes likely after generating about 100,000 of them (see "[Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)" for a more precise statement and formulas).

If you can accept a small selection of letters (a to f) in addition to digits, the following may work better for you:`SecureRandom.hex(5)`. Here, the chance of duplicates is smaller, and the chance becomes likely after generating about a million of them.

Remember, though, that generally, random identifiers produce a risk of duplicates, so you need a way to check random IDs for uniqueness.

An alternative is to encrypt a sequential counter with a secret key (e.g., via format-preserving encryption). Although this approach preserves uniqueness, there is the complication of having to secure the secret key from attacks.